# Webinar Application with Voice Streaming

Tags: java, jsf-2, applet, jplayer

I am trying to make a webinar app that will take the teacher's voice input and broadcast it to the students.

It is in a very early stage of design, But I think that putting out a call for help on the SO wouldn't hurt.

The technological platform will be Java/jQuery/JSF, since the rest of the site is built on this. I will steer off of flash/flex because I know nil about them.

So far I am thinking of putting a Java Applet on the teacher's page, recording its mic input. The applet must be signed, etc etc, but it seems that the Java Audio API (JMF, etc) did not receive much love from Oracle and may be stuck in a old version. I fould very sparse info googling for it.

On the audience side, maybe using another audio player applet, but it may be overkill, when I can go with jPlayer for example.

I think I can code the audio recording applet on my own, and stream the data back to the server (running JSF on Tomcat) - and I will post the applet skeleton here on SO soon :)

**As there must be a question, here it goes:**

- How can I make jPlayer capture the data from the JSF server? Or in
  other words, what the JSF server needs to do in order to make the streaming
  audio captured by the applet available to jPlayer?

---

*I doubt someone has a ready solution, and I am sorry for the broad question. As my research goes, I will share it here on SO. Probably there will be more questions, they will be linked in the comments.*

*Thank you very much for your eyeball time reading this.*

Comment: hi , have you found any good way ?

Comment: The project was cancelled by a shift in management. So it is stalled indefenitely. :(